# How do I use jquery to post a custom class?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to create a simple contact form for my MVC app. So far it all works fine but I'm now taking it a step further and trying to use ajax to post back the form data. The problem is that my [HttpPost] method expects my ContactViewModel but how do I send this back to the method from jQuery?

Here's my front end code:

```
@model  MSExport.Models.ContactViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Contact";
}
@section HeaderScripts
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.post("/Contact/Index", { ... }, function (data) {
                // Do whatever
            });
        });        
    </script>
}

<h1>Contact</h1>
@using (Html.BeginForm()) { 
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true) 
    <fieldset> 
        <legend>Contact Us</legend> 
        <div class="editor-label"> 
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name) 
        </div> 
        <div class="editor-field"> 
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name) 
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name) 
        </div> 
        <div class="editor-label"> 
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email) 
        </div> 
        <div class="editor-field"> 
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email) 
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email) 
        </div> 
        <div class="editor-label"> 
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Message) 
        </div> 
        <div class="editor-field"> 
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Message) 
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Message) 
        </div> 
        <p> 
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" /> 
        </p> 
    </fieldset> 
}
```

and here's my back-end code:

```
public class ContactController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Contact/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(new ContactViewModel());
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(ContactViewModel contactVM)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View(contactVM);
            }

            var contact = new Contact
            {
                Name = contactVM.Name,
                Email = contactVM.Email,
                Message = contactVM.Message
            };

            // Do whatever with new contact class

            return RedirectToAction("Thankyou");
        }

        public ActionResult Thankyou()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }

public class ContactViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Message { get; set; }     
    }

public class Contact
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
    }
```

The '...' above is where I define the data to be sent back to the method but I'm not sure what I put here? Do I recreate my custom class here using JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a class in Javascript (using the `function` syntax) with the matching members, or simply pass a dictionary (e.g. `{ Name: 'John', Email: 'john@example.com', ...}`. The model binder should (in most cases) be able to map that to your concrete view model when you POST to the controller method.

Answer (score 2):

From your HttpPost Index action return Json like this

```
return Json(new { name = contact.Name});
```

and in jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.post("/Contact/Index", { ... }, function (data) {
                alert(data.name);
            });
        });        
    </script>
```